# hierarchical linear model with moderation in R

Tags: random-effects-model

Could someone please check if my model fit is correct??? Thank you!!!!!!

Here is the background: participants fill out one baseline survey and seven identical follow-up surveys during a week. I have a variable BN in the baseline, DN and DE in the followup. In summary, each participant has a baseline measure BN and 5-7 DN and DE daily measures. The participants are differentiated by ID. I need to find out whether the associations between DN and DE are moderated by baseline_need.

Here is my code:

mod = lmer(DE ~  DN + BN : DE  + (1 + DE| ID), data)